# How to fix action menu location on action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to fix this problem i am having. My Action Menu is showing up over the Action Bar. I want it to show below. Like it normally should. The theme i am using is Theme.AppCompat.

This is how i want it: http://postimg.org/image/m7lrmwl09/

This is how i have it: http://postimg.org/image/yqiutbnob/

I have tried changing the theme but i need an AppCompat theme.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem, this is the new standard behavior for Material Design:
http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-usage

Comment: How do i change it, don't really like it.